# Named slots in layout can not be used within NuxtPage

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I think I'm missing something essential..

I want to use the layout functionality like it is described in the [official docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts#setting-another-layout)
My layout file has named slots for header and footer. These slots need to be addressed from within the page.

app.vue

```html
<template>
    <NuxtLayout>
        <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

layouts/default.vue

```html
<template>
    <header>
        <slot name="header" />
    </header>
    <main>
        <slot />
    </main>
    <footer>
        <slot name="footer" />
    </footer>
</template>
```

pages/index.vue

```html
<template>
    <template #header>
        HEADER
    </template>
</template>
```

I'm getting this error

```
[plugin:vite:vue] Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node. Apply appropriate transforms first.
```

I think thats because i have the template tag as the root of the page component, but [google says that the template tags need to be on the root level](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5748)

Answer (score 1):

This his how you make `/pages/index.vue` work and render the text in the header slot:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout name="default">
      <template #header> HEADER </template>
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
```

But I am not sure wheter this is what you really want to do. If you want to have a common header and footer, it is better to put this code right inside `/layouts/default.vue` or make a component and use it there.

I prepared a quick example of how I would setup layout with common header and footer:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-kzomp4

Also note that unless you really need to switch between more than one different layout in your application, Nuxt developers [recommend](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/18957) not messing with layouts at all and put the code right into `app.vue`. But that depends on your real use-case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this is not quite the preferred solution. It kind of contradicts the idea of "layouts" since i could use any component like this. I hoped for being able to use named slots within `NuxtPage` in combination with `NuxtLayout`

Comment: I believe the "idea of layouts" is to condense common rendering logic into one place. And to allow quick switching, if you have more than one common patterns for your pages... But the components in `/page` folder are meant to be matched just once based on current route. `/pages/index.vue` should contain uniqe content to be displayed after `/` URL path is visited. It doesn't make much sense to me you want to use it just for rendering header. On the contrary, that's what `/components` ARE meant for.

Comment: I have more than the header .. however, named slots are pointless if its not possible to use them. Using a component (in fact NuxtLayout is a component by itself) is what I've done before. I was happy to see that there is layout functionality now, but the way it can/can't be used is a pity